# Increase size of labels automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-visualization

I need to show the full text of the labels on the vertical Axis of a https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

However the text is variable, so I don't know how much space I will need.

What I did was increase the width and height of the chart, but this is not always necesary.

Is there any way I can set up the chart so it will automatically change the size of the text?

[image: Example image]

EDIT
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should add which charting library you're using to the question and its tags. This doesn't look like a general JS, CSS, or jQuery question.

Comment: updated my question to include the chart library I'm using